# gradle difference between testRuntime and testProvided

Tags: gradle

Single question:

In gradle, there are several configurations provided out of the box.
For example `testCompile`, `testProvided`, `testRuntime`, `javaCompile`, `javaProvided`, and so on...

Could you explain what's the difference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Configurations allow you to scope dependencies. Given this configuration hierarchy:

```
testRuntime -> testCompile -> runtime -> compile
```

Each configuration helps you limit where your dependencies are. *Runtime configurations allow you to include a dependency, but not have it as a compile dependency. This is helpful when you want to keep a framework loosely coupled from a project. A runtime dependency means that you need it for the app to run, but don't need it to compile.

The same thing applies for the test* configurations.

Ref:

- Gradle Docs - [Dependency configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#configurations)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Ethan's answer: the `provided` configurations contain dependencies that are used during compile but are not packaged to the final artifact. This is for example useful when you develop for a container that provides these dependencies already in its installation.